# I installed expires header at IIS 7.5 but still do not show at Firefox firebug yslow or .net plugin

Tags: http-headers, iis-7.5, installation, yslow

I did setup like this

[image]

but result is still like this:

[image: http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/8227/resultgj.png]

Where do I make a mistake?

---

it was casued by google analytics code. i had to setup this way

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1'], ['_setDomainName', 'www.xxxxxxx.com'], ['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the expires header won't show.

You have set up the webserver to expire content "after 14 days".

This will result in **"Cache-control: max-age=xxxx"** header. Not the **"Expires"** header.

Comment: do what? expire the content in 14 days? you've everything correct